# How to correctly dequeue certain Elementor css files in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I use Elementor to build my website and there are a lot of functionalities that I'm not using but are none the less loaded on every page of my website. So I decided to dequeue the css files I'm not using in my child theme's functions.php and dequeue the css files which I'm only partially using, replacing them with a 'cleaned-up' version of the file.

This is how I wanted to start doing it:

```
function adg_dequeue_unnecessary_files() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'elementor-frontend' ); // remove Elementor's custom-frontend.min.css
        wp_deregister_style( 'elementor-frontend' );

    wp_register_style( 'new-elementor-frontend-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-frontend.min.css' ); // Purified replacement for Elementor's custom-frontend.min.css
        wp_enqueue_style( 'new-elementor-frontend-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adg_dequeue_unnecessary_files' );
```

But while the second part of my function adds my new custom css file nicely, the first part removes almost 10 other Elementor's css files along with the one I actually wanted to dequeue.

This is the list of files being dequeued:

- custom-frontend.min.css
- post-1501.css (this is the css file of the page I was looking at while making these changes)
- frontend-legacy.min.css
- post-1396.css (some global Elementor's css)
- post-3556.css (this one and the 5 below are templates from a plugin I'm using across my website)
- post-4473.css
- post-5653.css
- post-3489.css
- post-3464.css
- post-3458.css

I'm guessing it has something to do with the handler 'elementor-frontend' not being correct. The custom-frontend.min.css file had the 'elementor-frontend-css' ID in the link tag of the HTML code, so I was guessing the handler from there.

Does anyone know how I can dequeue only the custom-frontend.min.css file?

After that I wanted to dequeue these files as well:

- animations.min.css
- elementor-icons.min.css
- global.css
- frontend-legacy.min.css
- swiper.min.js

I've been browsing this for a few days and I'm starting to feel lost, so any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can dequeue the Elementor CSS file with the use of `wp_deregister_style` and `wp_dequeue_style`. For this, you need to pass the CSS file **handle name**. You can use the below code to dequeue the Elementor plugin `global.css` file.

```
function dequeue_elementor_global__css() {
  wp_dequeue_style('elementor-global');
  wp_deregister_style('elementor-global');
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'dequeue_elementor_global__css', 9999);
```

> Here **elementor-global** is the handle name of the global.css file. You can get any file handle name by stylesheet id. 
> For example:
> **If any stylesheet id is the `elementor-global-css` then this file handle will be `elementor-global`**

Comment: Hi, that works for global Elementor css, but not for elementor-frontend. There are certain dependencies tied to it and I can't remove only one file like that.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that all Elementor frontend styles, e.g. your post-1234.css files, are children of 'elementor-frontend', which means if you unload it, none of them will load.

If you load your new, optimised frontend.min.css files with the same name, then it should work.

e.g.

```
function adg_dequeue_unnecessary_files() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'elementor-frontend' ); // remove Elementor's custom-frontend.min.css
        wp_deregister_style( 'elementor-frontend' );

    wp_register_style( 'elementor-frontend', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-frontend.min.css' ); // Purified replacement for Elementor's custom-frontend.min.css
        wp_enqueue_style( 'elementor-frontend' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'adg_dequeue_unnecessary_files' );
```

Also. Can you not just add your custom-frontend.min.css to the relevant location in your Child Theme and it will overwrite the Parent theme version by default?

Comment: That was my idea as well and I did exactly as you said but I ended up with all children unloaded and only my new css file loaded. It appears that Elementor's frontend css file isn't loaded exactly like this in the first place, so it doesn't work. I ended up solving this using a plugin, which wasn't my ideal solution to be honest. But until I find some other solution, it will do.

Comment: Note: This removes all of the column widget set up that Elementor offers. So whilst it stopped overriding my bootstrap styling, it put everything in single column where I had them in multiple column layouts.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. Tested on a few pages and posts:

```
add_action( 'elementor/frontend/after_enqueue_styles', function() { 
    wp_deregister_style( 'elementor-frontend' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'elementor-frontend' );
    wp_register_style( 'elementor-frontend', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/custom-elementor-front-end.css' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'elementor-frontend', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/custom-elementor-front-end.css' );
} );
```

Comment: This doensn't seem to remove the Elementor CSS

Comment: It removes only frontend.min.css, and not the individual css files generated for each post which are dependencies. That was the original question. The point is that elementor-frontend css file is big and usually 90-95% unused, while individual posts css files are smaller and on target. If you want to remove them all, enqueue your own css file with a custom name not with elementor handle name, or bundle everything in your main style.css file and just dequeue elementor-frontend, that will dequeue all its dependencies

Comment: @Nikobokan how did you solve bundling the elementor individual post css in your main style.css file?